# How do I get my dummy app to use the Engine's template engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, template-engine, rails-engines, slim-lang

I have a Rails Engine I'm working on and the gemspec has this:

```
s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails"
s.add_development_dependency "combustion"
s.add_development_dependency "capybara"
s.add_development_dependency "factory_girl_rails"
s.add_development_dependency "ffaker"
s.add_development_dependency "draper"
s.add_runtime_dependency "sqlite3"
s.add_runtime_dependency "slim-rails"
s.add_runtime_dependency "sass-rails"
s.add_runtime_dependency "jquery-rails"
s.add_runtime_dependency "rails", "~> 3.2"
```

However upon going to the correct controller/action I get this error:

```
Missing template countdown/subscriptions/index, countdown/application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/krainboltgreene/Repository/ruby/countdown/spec/dummy/app/views" * "/Users/krainboltgreene/Repository/ruby/countdown/app/views"
```

Notice the handlers part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the dummy application not loading Devise. What I had to do was require it inside `config/application.rb` and then it worked. Perhaps you just need to `require 'slim'` there and it will work too?

Comment: We talking `spec|test/dummy/config` or `config/`? I'll try both of course, but having it here would help others.

Comment: `spec|test/dummy/config`. An engine has no `config/application.rb`... because it's an engine! :)

Comment: This answer explains the problem but doesn't provide the correct approach/solution. [Hannah's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2048318/hannah-christine-deffenbaugh) suggestion that we should require the gem in `lib/your_engine.rb` is the right solution.

Answer (score 10):

You should require the gem in `lib/your_engine.rb`. If you only require it in your dummy app's `config/application.rb`, then others are going to have this same problem when include your engine in their apps.

This can be especially confusing because in regular Rails app development. It's easy to rely on `Bundler.require` to load all of your gems for you.

Reference: [5 Reasons to Avoid `Bundler.require`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210922232941/http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/12/5-reasons-to-avoid-bundler-require)